# Unable to derive arbitrary::Arbitrary for a struct with a member that is an associated type

Tags: generics, rust, fuzzing

This came up in the context of a small structure-aware fuzzing project. If we are using automated trait derivation against a struct type that involves [associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#specifying-placeholder-types-in-trait-definitions-with-associated-types), a problem appears to arise.

In a bit more detail, the [structure-aware fuzzing page](https://rust-fuzz.github.io/book/cargo-fuzz/structure-aware-fuzzing.html) involves automated trait derivation which works recursively. If we have a struct made up of other structs/types, the derivation will assume that the same trait has been derived on subfields and work down recursively to construct the final trait. If I'm not mistaken, this is a somewhat usual pattern in automated trait derivation of compound types. For example, if we have the `Rgb` struct type, deriving the `Arbitrary` trait relies on the fact that the trait can also be derived against `u8`:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "arbitrary", derive(arbitrary::Arbitrary))]
pub struct Rgb {
    pub r: u8,
    pub g: u8,
    pub b: u8,
}
```

This approach can be extended if generics are in play, which is nice:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "arbitrary", derive(arbitrary::Arbitrary))]
pub struct MyType {
    y: u8,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "arbitrary", derive(arbitrary::Arbitrary))]
pub struct Point<S> {
    x: S,
}
```

The compiler does not trip up when trying to derive the `Arbitrary` trait for the `Point<S>` type, even though it is a generic, and in all generality, it may not be known how to derive the trait for some `S` types. If we refer  to `Point<MyType>` and the `Arbitrary` trait is derived for `MyType` (as it is in the code), the compilation checks out fine.

If we try to use an *associated type*:

```rust
trait RawData {
    type Elem;
    fn hello();
}

impl RawData for u8 {
    type Elem = u32;
    fn hello() {
        println!("hi");
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "arbitrary", derive(arbitrary::Arbitrary))]
pub struct Point<S>
where
    S: RawData,
{
    y: S::Elem, // problem!
}
```

The compiler can't derive the `Arbitrary` trait for `Point<S>`, since the `struct` contains a `S::Elem` field:

```
18 | #[cfg_attr(feature = "arbitrary", derive(arbitrary::Arbitrary))]
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Arbitrary<'_>` is not implemented for `<S as RawData>::Elem`
   |
   = note: required by `arbitrary`
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `arbitrary::Arbitrary` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

It appears like the associated types and generics behave differently here.

- Can this be resolved without significant refactoring (such as replacing associated types by generics)?
- Is this this nuance on generics and associated types documented/discussed?

Comment: *The compiler can't derive the `Arbitrary` trait* — it's not the _compiler_ that implemented this. The developers of the arbitrary derive implemented that (the compiler just runs their code).

Comment: You'll need to add the trait bound `S::Elem: Arbitrary`. Whether that's something you can ask the derive to do or may need to do by hand is up to the implementation of the derive.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks, good point on the compiler running the Arbitrary crate code, I looked up how custom `derive` directives are implemented now. 

I could modify the RawData trait specification to have something like `type Elem : arbitrary::Arbitrary`. Also, I could implement the Arbitrary trait on `u32`, since  u32 is the type that `Elem` is set to. Simply something like `impl Arbitrary for u32 { ...`.   

Is this what you meant?